# CSS inverted trapezium when width will differ

Tags: css

I need to make the shape below, which will contain some text.  Sometimes the text will be longer, sometimes shorter so I can use any fixed widths.

```
**********
 *      *
  ******
```

This the is code I have - I'm wondering if there's a way I can tag an image on to the beginning and the end of the span.  The height won't change so that would probably be the best in terms of cross browser solutions...

```
<div class="trapizium_holder">
    <span id="trapizium"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: you can do it with css `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes. but it will take a minute to figure out.

Comment: "This the is code I have" - so basically you don't have anything yet :D. Check this link http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Be aware that `:before` and `:after` don't work in IE7 and earlier (on the off chance that you need to support those browsers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### One Wrapper Only Needed (IE8+)

[**This fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7hYz/4/) demonstrates that only a single wrapper is needed. It uses a single pseudo-element to get the angles. The wrapper must either be floated or an inline-block. Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="trapizium">
   Test text
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.trapizium {
    position: relative;
    float: left; /* wrap the text */
    clear: left; /* for demo */
    margin: 10px 20px; /* left/right margin will be diagonal width */
    /* needs some set height */
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: .2em 0;
    background-color: cyan;
}

.trapizium:before {
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -20px; /* stick out into margined area */
    z-index: -1; /* make it the background */
    border: 20px solid transparent; /* left/right diagonals */
    border-top: 1.4em solid cyan;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cs6fY/)

```
#trapizium {
    border-top: 100px solid blue;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

You may have to absolute position your text into your shapes. This uses borders to make the shape, and has no height.